# How to show events in the dhtmlx scheduler within the database data

Tags: javascript, ajax, dhtmlx, dhtmlx-scheduler

Please suggest to me or explain **how to show events in dhtmlx scheduler with the dynamic data**.

---

**Here is my booking page**
[Booking Page Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yCCWK.png)

After Page loading, I want to show event like this
[Booking Event Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ABcdw.png)

This *event* is made with **static** data. I just want to show with **dynamic** data in the database.
*Note: I use cakephp2 framework.*

This is Static event with static data(I don’t want this static event)

```
scheduler.parse([
     { id: 4, start_date: “2019-11-7 16:00”, end_date: “2019-11-7 17:00”, text: “English lesson” } 
]);
```

So I declared variable to get data from database in JavaScript like this

```
var booking_date_ajax = $data[‘booking_date’];
var booking_time_from_ajax= $data[‘booking_time_from’];
var booking_time_to_ajax= $data[‘booking_time_to’];
```

And use these code to show event but still not working

```
scheduler.parse([
     { id: 1, start_date: ‘booking_date_ajax booking_time_from_ajax’, end_date: ‘booking_date_ajax booking_time_to_ajax’, text: “English lesson” }
]);
```

**or**

```
scheduler.parse([
    { id: 1, start_date: booking_date_ajax booking_time_from_ajax, end_date: booking_date_ajax booking_time_to_ajax’, text: “English lesson” }
]);
```

Comment: Can you show us the variable values of your ajax dates?

Comment: Also what is the values you're providing to `start_date` and `end_date` what is that? Those aren't variables at all.